# JMeter4.0 - Sampler Request Plugin Doesn't Take the updated counter value

Tags: java, performance, jmeter, jmx, beanshell

I really need your help. 
In JMeter 4.0 in my JMX script, I tried to create and increase counter variable and I do that with the BeanShell Sampler before the sampler in while loop. The problem that the counter value himself increased but the sampler takes the wrong value from him, not the updated value. Much thanks for all of you.
Or.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Amend your code to look like:

   ```
   temp = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("counterPlugin")) + 1;
   vars.put("counterPlugin", String.valueOf(temp));
   log.info(vars.get("counterPlugin"));
   ```

   2. [Since JMeter 3.1 it is recommend to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for any scripting operations so consider migrating to [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)
   3. Since [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4) you have `${__jm__Loop Controller__idx}` variable which holds the current iteration number of the Loop Controller

      [image: JMeter Loop Controller and Counter]